# How git knows that branch is up to date? `Error: There is no tracking information for the current branch.`

Tags: git, git-pull

I am curious how `git` knows that branch is up to date if it complaints about lack of tracking information for this branch?

```
git pull -v --rebase=merges
POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)
From https://github.com/org/repo
 = [up to date]        PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked -> origin/PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked
```

From the output above we can see that my branch was bound to origin repo:

```
PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked -> origin/PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked
```

But from the next message below we see that it does not:

```
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with
```

Comment: What is the current branch? Which version is your Git? It seems that the lines `POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)` and `terraform_remove_tags_all` are not Git normal output. Is any Git hook invoked?

Comment: @ElpieKay: Current branch is `PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked`. The `git version 2.43.0`. I do not know what `POST ...` means. The .git/hooks folder contains only `*.sample` files. `terraform_remove_tags_all` is a different `= [up to date]` branch I did not deleted from output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am curious how git knows that branch is up to date if it complaints
> about lack of tracking information for this branch?

It does not - as you correctly wrote. You are misunderstanding the output of git.

> From the output above we can see that my branch was bound to origin repo:
>
> PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked -> origin/PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked

No, that is a misunderstanding. The full output is:

> = [up to date]        PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked -> origin/PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked

This output is only printed because you used `git pull -v` - it would not be printed without the `-v`. This output simply informs you that:

- during the "fetch" part of the pull, git found a remote-tracking branch   "origin/PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked" in your repo
- this remote-tracking branch was synchronised with the branch "PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked" in the upstream repository "origin" (a GitHub repo)
- and that these two branches were already in sync (indicated by the "=")

This says nothing about your *local* branch "PLTFM-541_POSTGRES_PASSWORD_is_leaked", even though this local branch has the same name as the remote branch.

The crucial thing to understand is:

Git has **local branches** and **remote-tracking branches**. Both branches are actually stored in your local repository (so both are local in a sense), but they are still different.

However, you can "link" a local branch to a remote-tracking branch by setting a remote-tracking branch as the so-called "upstream branch" or "tracking branch" of a local branch. This is what the command `git branch --set-upstream-to=...` does, and what happens by default to the "master" branch when you clone a repository.

You can see this "tracking information" in the output of e.g. "git branch -vv":

```
$ git branch -vv
feature/do-stuff    b234657 [origin/feature/do-some-stuff] fix issues
* master            44ea3fa [origin/master] implement stuff
mylocalbranch       54ad3ea do local stuff
```

Here, you have three local branches: "feature/do-stuff", "master", "mylocalbranch". The first two have remote-tracking branches as their tracking/upstream branches (shown in angle brackets), the third has no upstream branch (like in your case).

For more explanation, see e.g. [the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), chapter [3.5 Git Branching - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: So if I understand correct for third branch the output of `git pull -v` will be `= [up to date] mylocalbranch -> origin/mylocalbranch` while `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`will show: 
`7b093ea0 (HEAD ->mylocalbranch) do local stuff`
`b3cae47b (origin/mylocalbranch) stuff on remote` Is this correct?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: No, `git pull -v` will not list mylocalbranch at all - "pull" only concerns remote-tracking branches. `git log` does not distinguish between local and remote-tracking branches. Also, there is no "origin/mylocalbranch". because the branch only exists locally.

Comment: But in my case the brunch exists locally and remotely. It looks like when I create my branch and push its content to remote server the track information is not setup automatically. The confusion was that local branch `branch_name` has same display name as the branch from `origin` server which is stored locally. After `git pull -v` the local branch still is not in sync with remote branch which is saved locally. From my perspective it should be spelled like `local/origin/branch_name` instead of just `branch_name`: `= [ up to date ] local/origin/branch_name -> origin/branch_name`.

Comment: Yes, when you push a branch, you must instruct git to set up tracking information, it will not do so automatically. You need to use `git push -u `.